# Verificación de vacíos a childrens en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día, tengo en mi página el siguiente código para verificar que no pueda hacerse un nuevo append si hay algún input vacío, evidentemente no funciona, quiero pensar que es porque al dar estilo a los inputs estos en encerrados en divs (Como puede verse en la creación del append) Me gustaría saber cómo puedo corregir esto.

```js
var texts = $(".texts");//Toma el div contenedor de todos los input
        var elementos = texts.children;//Toma los input(encerrados en divs), o debería dentro de "texts"
        for(var index = 0; index < elementos.length; index++) {
            if(elementos[index].val().length > 0){
                var principal = document.createElement('div');
                principal.className = "group";
                var txtnombre = document.createElement('input');
                txtnombre.type = "text";
                txtnombre.name = "Nombre";
                txtnombre.className = "name";
                txtnombre.required = "true";
                var spanh = document.createElement('span');
                spanh.className = "highlight";  
                var spanb = document.createElement('span');
                spanb.className = "bar";  
                var lblnombre = document.createElement('label');
                lblnombre.innerHTML = "Nombre de la especie";

                principal.appendChild(txtnombre);              
                principal.appendChild(spanh);              
                principal.appendChild(spanb);
                principal.appendChild(lblnombre);
                $(".texts").append(principal); 

                console.log("works");
            }else{

            }`
```

Comment: Deberías subir el HTML para ver la estructura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, el `input` lo tienes dentro del div, por lo que para acceder a su valor debes hacerlo así: `elementos.children[index].children[0].value`.

Pero en todo caso, creo que tu acercamiento no iba del todo bien encaminado... primero deberías comprobar todos los input y después crear los elementos; yo probaría algo así:

```js
// Con [].slice.call() convertimos el HTMLCollection a un array
elementos = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('texts').children);

// Devolvemos una copia del array sólo con los elementos 
// que contengan un input vacío
elementos = elementos.filter((elem) => {        
    return elem.children[0].value === "" || elem.children[0].value === null;
});

// Si no hay elementos, creamos uno...
if (!elementos.length) {

    // Tu código para crear los componentes

}
```

Aquí te dejo un [jsfiddle funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/385kx6pr/)